# Moment.tz("Europe/Berlin").startOf("week") returning Sunday instead of Monday

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

Certain timezones start the week on a Monday rather than Sunday, f.e. Germany. I expected `Moment.tz("Europe/Berlin").startOf("week")` to return Monday but instead it returns Sunday. Any way to workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

You can use [`Intl.Locale.prototype.getWeekInfo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/getWeekInfo), *but Firefox doesn't support it at all.*

```js
const fallBackStartOfWeek = {
  'de-DE': 1,
  'en-US': 7
};

const getFallbackStartOfWeek = (tz) => 
    Object.keys(fallBackStartOfWeek).includes(tz) 
        ? fallBackStartOfWeek[tz] : 7; // fallback to sunday;
        
const getStartOfTheWeek = (date, tz) => {
  const locale = new Intl.Locale(tz);
  let firstDay = -1;
  if (locale.getWeekInfo) { // safari
    firstDay = locale.getWeekInfo().firstDay;
  } else if (locale.weekInfo) { // chrome, edge, opera
    firstDay = locale.weekInfo.firstDay;
  } else { // firefox. not implemented yet
    firstDay = getFallbackStartOfWeek(tz);
  }
  return moment(date).day(firstDay).toString();
}

const germanStartOfWeek = getStartOfTheWeek('2023-11-07', 'de-DE');
const usStartOfWeek = getStartOfTheWeek('2023-11-07', 'en-US');

console.log({
  german: germanStartOfWeek,
  us: usStartOfWeek
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.43/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Browser Compatibility: [Intl: Locale: getWeekInfo](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_locale_getweekinfo)

---

**Old Answer:**

You can use `getDay('Monday')` or `getDay(0)` to get Monday on all the timezone locale.

```js
const mondayBerlin = moment('2023-11-07').tz('Europe/Berlin').day('Monday');
console.log({
  date: moment(mondayBerlin).format('yyyy-MM-DD'),
  day: moment(mondayBerlin).format('dddd')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.43/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Getting Monday isn’t the same as getting the start of the week for a locale, though, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton no. its not, I read your other comment. OP was asking for a workaround. This is the only one I could fnd

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified. I am looking for the start of the week to return the expected calendar day relative to the locale. In US, start of week is Sunday, but in Europe, it's Monday

Comment: @user17443811 updated answer. I am afraid that I don't have an answer that works for you in production yet.

Answer (score 0):

Start of week is dependent on locale (see link below to docs and an example).

See [here](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/cxd9yl95ip--get-beginning-and-end-of-week-with-momentjs) and [here](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/02-get-set/07-weekday/)

Comment: Could you summarize the links in your answer? Link-only answers are discouraged as they become useless if the links stop working.

Comment: I believe the OP is aware of this, and is asking why it’s returning Sunday when (in my experience anyway) the German calendar starts on Monday. (As it should, never understood starting on Sunday.) OTOH I learned this in HS German class 40 yrs ago so maybe they’ve changed as a nation ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

The starting day of the week is an aspect of *locale*, not time zone.  They are independent concepts.  You can use one or the other, or both.

```js
// start of the week in your local time zone and the default locale
const m1 = moment().startOf('week');

// start of the week in your local time zone, using a German locale
const m2 = moment().locale('de').startOf('week');

// start of the week in Germany's time zone, using the default locale
const m3 = moment.tz('Europe/Berlin').startOf('week');

// start of the week in Germany's time zone, using a German locale
const m4 = moment.tz('Europe/Berlin').locale('de').startOf('week');

console.log('m1:', m1.toString());
console.log('m2:', m2.toString());
console.log('m3:', m3.toString());
console.log('m4:', m4.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.43/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

I think you are expecting the behavior of the *fourth* example above, though you are using the third.

Also keep in mind that [Moment.js is generally considered obsolete](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), and should only be used on legacy projects.